# BackupExec 10d crashing 2k3 server

Tags: backupexec, tape, windows-server-2003-r2, server-crashes

There are two weeks now since I'm doing repository-like backup, because BE10d is crashing the file server.
The computer is a NEC Express 5800, 2xXeon, 1 GB RAM, 4 SCSI drives in RAID 5 w/ spare, one 160 GB IDE and 4mm tape (connected to onboard SCSI Adaptec). It run Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86), up-to-date, coming from an Windows 2000 Server through update. Antivirus is Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8.
The problem started up when the last security fixes from Microsoft were installed (it was a bunch of them, so I don't know which one exactly has caused the problem). Now, after any operation that involves the tape, the server goes BSOD with message related to RDR_File_System and mrxsmb.sys file. Since then, I have been looking at Micosoft's, Symantec's and various other sites with connection to these. At the time of the first occurrence, BE was just with SP1. This morning I made SP4, but the result of tape erasure was the same blue screen. mrxsmb.sys fixes from Microsoft don't apply since I have already SP2 and all the security patches. There is no A/V issue, it does the same with it disabled.
I am stuck now with synchronizing the needed files onto another server (like) and I hope that this is just temporary.

Any help much and greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Valentin

Comment: Hello everyone, I have made this morning another test, backup to disk. It has crashed again, same message, but I have not checked the "disk" properties before running and I think it run out of allocated space. And, the tape was not disabled. I will try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was the motherboard's fault. Few weeks later it crashed the system. Luckily, I had backups BUT, more important, the RAID card was an add-on card and I was able to get it into another computer, together with the SCSI cage.
No data was lost, but time, yes.